# How do I fix the behavior of the "actionNone" imeOption on an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

If I set imeOptions to "actionNone" on an EditText...

`android:imeOptions="actionNone"`

... the bottom right button on the virtual keyboard will have a return carriage symbol.

On most devices, tapping this will send the user to the next EditText.  However, on my device (Nexus S running Android 4.1), it will add a space to the EditText.  How do I make this always move to the next EditText?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `nextFocusForward` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#nextFocusForward

> Defines the next view to give focus to when the next focus is FOCUS_FORWARD If the reference refers to a view that does not exist or is part of a hierarchy that is invisible, a RuntimeException will result when the reference is accessed.

Example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Also you may want to consider `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to make a "Return" button to "Next" which sounds like it moves to the next field, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this with no success.  When imeOptions is set to actionNone, the return key will create a space in the EditText instead of moving to the next EditText like it does on other devices.

Comment: I see what you are saying now.  `actionNone` cannot work with `nextFocusForward`.  I can make it work only when I set `actionNext`.  If you want to keep `actionNone`, I think you need to override EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom keyboard on your device?
It can be the problem.